# Get all the folders and sub-folders in side a directory

Tags: vb.net, directory

I am learning VB.net, I would like to know how to get all the folders and sub-folder s inside a directory and how to add them all to a listbox. I would also like it to list the folders while it is scanning like showing the current folders found. I have tried a few things but they never seem to work. I have tried this:

```
Sub GetDirectories(ByVal StartPath As String, ByRef DirectoryList As ArrayList)
    Dim Dirs() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)
    DirectoryList.AddRange(Dirs)
    For Each Dir As String In Dirs
        GetDirectories(Dir, DirectoryList)
    Next
    For Each item In DirectoryList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DirList As New ArrayList
    GetDirectories("c:\hexing\", DirList)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
    Dim DirList As New ArrayList
    Dim Dirs() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)
    DirList.AddRange(Dirs)
    For Each Dir As String In Dirs
        GetDirectories(Dir, DirectoryList)
    Next
    Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub
```

**(Or)**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("c:\Program Files")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
        Next
End Sub
```

**Edit**

According to [VB.NET 05, List Folder, SubFolders, and Sub SubFolders](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/796068-vb-net-05-list-folder-subfolders-sub-subfolders#post3164770):

> The most efficient way would be to use recursivity:

```
 Private Function getAllFolders(ByVal directory As String) As String()
        'Create object
        Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
        'Array to store paths
        Dim path() As String = {}
        'Loop through subfolders
        For Each subfolder As IO.DirectoryInfo In fi.GetDirectories()
            'Add this folders name
            Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
            path(path.Length - 1) = subfolder.FullName
            'Recall function with each subdirectory
            For Each s As String In getAllFolders(subfolder.FullName)
                Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
                path(path.Length - 1) = s
            Next
        Next
        Return path
 End Function
```

Comment: The second one doesn't get all the folders, I want it to get all the folders in the main directory, and then get all the sub-folders in those folders. Thanks anyway

Comment: @xGh0stSn1p3r See my edit . it will get you the all sub folders

Comment: Thanks, but at the start, it kinds freezes and just stays there for a while, can't move it or anything. Would there be any way to run it in the background so you could still move the form? Or even add each directory to a list box each time it has found one instead of just staying there? Thanks EDIT* it just says string[] array when on a listbox

Comment: Worked well for me. Had to make one change because function has a new name:. getAllFolders is now IO.Directory.GetDirectories(subfolder.FullName)

Answer (score 3):

use the [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) method.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo("path");

dinfo.GetDirectories();
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it works, but it doesn't get the sub-folders in the directory, I want it to get every sub-folder in every folder. Thanks anywa

Comment: IO.Directory.GetDirectories("main-directory-path", "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories) seems to get all the sub/child directories.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    GetDirectories(Label1.Text)
End Sub

Sub GetDirectories(ByVal StartPath As String)
    For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
        GetDirectories(Dir)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed my code as sample from "user10795772"(Thanks so much). But I use it to list out all files in all subfolders. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub GetDirectories(ByVal StartPath As String)
    For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Dir + vbCrLf)
       'just add on 30-Nov-2023 for list-out completely
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Dir)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(foundFile + vbCrLf)
        Next
       'end of add
        GetDirectories(Dir)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub gafad(ByVal mfd As String) 'Get all files all directories
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(mfd)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(foundFile + vbCrLf)
    Next

    For Each fd As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(mfd)
        If InStr(fd, "$") = False Then 'Not list for system folder
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(fd + vbCrLf)
            For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(fd)
                RichTextBox1.AppendText(foundFile + vbCrLf)
            Next
            GetDirectories(fd)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When use. just Call gafad("Directory")